# Why is cout undefined in my cpp if it's included in my header?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class A.h which has #include iostream

Then in B.h I #include A.h

Then in C.h I #include B.h

In C.cpp I am defining the print() function as

```
void C::print() const {
cout << "C has specs of: " << getSpecs() << endl;
}
```

The cout is undefined for C.cpp why is that?

I thought that since iostream was included in A.h and since B.h includes A.h and C.h includes B.h it would include iostream to be used in my C.cpp

Is there anyway to accomplish this without #including iostream on all my .h's?

I'm pretty new to inheritance and learning how that works right now.

Comment: Probably should be `std::cout`. But anyhow, this question is useless without the [mcve] you are told to include *before* posting your question.

Comment: Did you try clicking the link?

Comment: Yeah but what other information is needed about this question? Think every angle is covered.

Answer (score 5):

`cout` is in the namespace `std`. Use `std::cout` and `std::endl` instead of `cout` and `endl`.

Comment: Side question: Do you think cout is the correct term to use for a print() function? Or is there a better way to do it so that cerr would work with that as well?

Comment: @bakedtaco No no no; Comments are **not** for new questions. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use `std::cerr` with print, but what you could do is have print take in a reference to an `std::istream` and print it to that.

Answer (score 0):

along with @fuzzything44's answer you could also use

```
using namespace::std;
```

at the top of your .cpp file or even put it in a common header.

The downside to doing that is that you junk-up the global namespace and could get ambiguous or conflicting terminals if you're including a lot of headers and doing a lot of *using namespace:xyz;* declarations;